# Converting iPhone app to Universal, XCode 5.1 using Xib files

Tags: ios7

Our application(only for iPhone) is already in iTunes. Which was developed using xib files. Now client wants same app should support both iPhone & iPad.
1.  If I change **"Development Info -> Devices -> Universal"**, will this work properly in both kind of devices?

A.  If **Yes** for above : If I change version of an app on iTunes with the same project name. How this can be achieved?

B.  What Settings should I do in plist file and with xib files?

Plz suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can change to Universal, so the application will **RUN** in both iPhone and iPad. Nonetheless, you will have to make changes to xib depending on the behavior of your app. Usually, iPads use list and detail views if it's in landscape, for example:

[image]

or in portrait view:

[image]

both look something like:

[image]

I want to point out again, on how your app behaves. Is not mandatory to use master-detail style, only if it fits your app.

And you can upload your binary to iTunes without problems. You could have problems if your app is using **Universal** and changing to iPhone or iPad **only**. And don't touch your plist.